# Java Streams Collectors.toList() with map() vs mapToInt()

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this object:

```java
String[] stringNum = new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"};
```

And I'm having some trouble to understand why this works:

```java
 List<Integer> intNums = Arrays.stream(stringNum)
                                .map(Integer::parseInt)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But this doesn't:

```java
 List<Integer> intNums = Arrays.stream(stringNum)
                                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If I understood to correctly then both `.map(Integer::parseInt)` and `.mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)` should return the same `IntStream` in this case to be handled by `.collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.map(Integer::parseInt)` returns a `Stream<Integer>`, not an `IntStream`. That's why the first snippet works.

`IntStream` doesn't have a `collect()` method that accepts a `Collector`. Therefore, the second snippet, which maps the `Stream<String>` to an `IntStream` cannot use `.collect(Collectors.toList())`.

To use the `collect(Supplier<R> supplier,ObjIntConsumer<R> accumulator,BiConsumer<R, R> combiner)` method of `IntStream` you can write:

```
List<Integer> intNums = Arrays.stream(stringNum)
                              .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                              .collect(ArrayList::new,ArrayList::add,ArrayList::addAll);
```

However, since your output is a `List<Integer>`, there's no point to create the intermediate `IntStream`, since that would require to box the `int`s later. Your `Stream<Integer>` variant (first snippet) makes more sense.

Comment: in addition to use `.map(Integer::valueOf)` instead `.map(Integer::parseInt)`

Comment: @HadiJ since `Integer.valueOf()` calls `Integer.parseInt()`, I believe it won't save anything. Either way a boxing will take place.

Answer (score 0):

`mapToInt` gives an `IntStream`, which doesn't have collect method taking a Collector argument.